# ADFS and Azure AD OAuth (User account ... from external identity provider ...)

Tags: azure, office365, adfs, azure-active-directory, office365-apps

Last few weeks I'm trying to solve one BIG problem with Azure Active Directory and Oauth authorization.

Now we have Azure AD tenant and API application in that tenant. We use it for Oauth and Office 365 API. Everything is ok, except one thing - our users cant change their passwords by themselves, they have to write administrators (>10K users). We want to enable ADFS and give them ability to change password.

We tried few times to enable ADFS and change auth type from Managed to Federated, but after that users cant log in our app.

If they click "log in" in our application it opens URL like:
https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=...&resource=https://outlook.office365.com/

When they try to sign in there they get error:
[image]
"User account ... from external identity provider ... is not supported for application ..."

AND!
If they sign in first in ADFS and after that sign in application - everything is ok.

So, what should we do to rnable ADFS and use API applications?

Sorry for bad description and bad english.

Comment: Hi, a couple clarifications... This error occurs after the user signs into ADFS, correct? Have you created this app as a mulit-tenant application? And is your application using the https://login.microsoftonline.com/common by design?

Comment: In other words, is this app intended to accept sign ins from users outside of your company/tenant?

Comment: App is multi-tenant, yes, error occurs after the user signs into ADFS.

Comment: And yes, application is using the https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2